# Django admin: How to reverse the order of list_filter?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-admin-tools

I have a dataset with models that show the year. What I need to do is reverse the order. By default, the Django admin interface shows the year by order of ascending number value (e.g. `2021`, `2022`, etc). What I'm aiming at is for the filter to display `2022`, `2021`.

models.py

```
...

def model(models.Model):
   year = models.IntegerField()
```

admin.py

```
...

class ModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   list_filter = ("year")
```

I think this is a very trivial question, but I haven't found the solution yet. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you can try to define default `ordering` in model `Meta` class:

```
class YourModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-year', ]
```

If it does not work for you, the only option for you is to use [custom filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/filters/#using-a-simplelistfilter) like this:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.contrib.admin import SimpleListFilter

class YearFilter(SimpleListFilter):
    title = _('year')

    parameter_name = 'year'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        qs = model_admin.queryset(request)
        return [(i, i) for i in qs.values_list('year', flat=True) \
                                  .distinct().order_by('-year')]

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        if self.value():
            return queryset.filter(year__exact=self.value())

class ModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = (YearFilter,)
```

Comment: I just implemented this on the admin site and it didn't work. It applied on the models but not on the filters.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I updated the model but the result remains unchanged.

Comment: I suppose the only option for you is to use [custom filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/filters/#using-a-simplelistfilter) then. Updated my answer.

Comment: @OleksiiTambovtsev How is ordering going to work ? `ordering = ['-year',]` you are having comma it should be tuple or remove that comma.

Comment: @Antisham due to [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/options/#ordering) this is a tuple or LIST of strings and/or query expressions. Why it should be a tuple or why I should remove that comma? `['-year',]` is the same as `['-year']`.

Comment: @OleksiiTambovtsev Please see difference between list and tuple. The docs you mention it shows no comma for single element so you have to remove it try it yourself.

Comment: @Antisham you didn’t answer the question “Why I should remove comma?”. You want to say, that it does not work with comma, or maybe other reason? :)

Comment: @Antisham and I know the difference between list and tuple, but that’s not the point.

Answer (score 0):

you can just use order_by and reverse. for example some pattern like this:

```
records=yourmodel.objects.filter(x=y).order_by('year').reverse
```